# How can I make a function that swaps two adjacent elements in a singly linked list by only changing the links?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

I am trying to make a function in my linked list that when I pass two integers to it. It would swap their nodes by changing what each of their nodes is pointing at. I am losing one of the nodes after the function finishes . How can I make it work ?

**This is the function itself**

```
    void linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int num1, int num2) {

    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }

    node *temp1, *temp2, *temp3;

    for (temp1 = head, temp2 = temp1->next; temp1->next != NULL; temp1 = temp1->next, temp2 = temp2->next) {
        cout << endl << "IN FOR" << endl;
        if (temp1->data == num1 && temp2->data == num2) {
            cout << "IN IF BEFORE NODES SWAP" << endl;
            // swap nodes
            cout << "Temp1 : " << temp1  << " --  Temp2 : " << temp2 << " --  Temp3 : " << temp3 << endl;
            temp3 = temp2->next;
            temp2->next = temp1;
            temp1->next = temp3;
            cout << "IN IF AFTER NODES SWAP" << endl;

        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

**This is the full implementation**

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class linkedList {
    private:
        node* head;

    public:
        linkedList();
        node* createNode(int num);
        void append(int num);
        // void add_as_first(int num);
        // void addAfter(int c, int num);
        void del(int num);
        void display();
        int count();
        void swapTwoAdjacent(int num1, int num2);
        // ~linkedList();   
};
int main (){
    linkedList List;

    List.display();

    int numNodes = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of nodes that you want to add: ";
    cin >> numNodes;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
        int current_element;
        cin >> current_element;
        List.append(current_element);
        cout << endl << current_element <<" has been appended to the list "<< endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl; 
    }

    List.display();
    // List.del(5);
    List.swapTwoAdjacent(4,6);
    List.display();
    // List.count();
    return 0;
}

// constructor initializes head to null
linkedList::linkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

// create node
node* linkedList::createNode(int num) 
{
    node* new_node;
    new_node = new node;
    new_node -> data = num;
    new_node -> next = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

void linkedList::append(int num)
{
    node *temp, *nNode;
    nNode = createNode(num);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = nNode;
    }

    else {
        temp = head;
        while(temp -> next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
        temp -> next = nNode;

    }
}

void linkedList::display()
{
    // if the list is empty
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "No nodes added yet!" << endl;
    }

    else {
        // create a temp variable to hold the heads
        node* temp = head;
        // as long as we haven't reached the end of the list
        while (temp != NULL) {
            // print current element
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            // go to the next node
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

int linkedList::count()
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << endl << "The list has " << counter << " elements." << endl;
    }

    else {


            for (node* temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

    cout << endl << "The list has " << counter << " elements." << endl;
}

void linkedList::del(int n) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "No elements are in the list " << endl;
    }
    node *temp1, *temp2;
        if (head-> next == NULL) {
                head = NULL;

                cout << endl << n << " was deleted" << endl;
                cout << endl << "Current elements in the list :" << endl << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
                this->display();
                return;
        }

        for (temp1 = head, temp2 = temp1->next; temp2 != NULL;  temp1 = temp1->next, temp2 = temp1->next) {
            if (temp1->data == n) {

                head = temp2;
                cout << endl << n << " was deleted" << endl;
                cout << endl << "Current elements in the list :" << endl << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
                this->display();
                break;
            }
            else if (temp2->data == n) {
                temp1->next = temp2->next;
                cout << endl << n << " was deleted" << endl;
                cout << endl << "Current elements in the list :" << endl << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
                this->display();
                break;
            }


            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
}

void linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int num1, int num2) {

    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }

    node *temp1, *temp2, *temp3;

    for (temp1 = head, temp2 = temp1->next; temp1->next != NULL; temp1 = temp1->next, temp2 = temp2->next) {
        cout << endl << "IN FOR" << endl;
        if (temp1->data == num1 && temp2->data == num2) {
            cout << "IN IF BEFORE NODES SWAP" << endl;
            // swap nodes
            cout << "Temp1 : " << temp1  << " --  Temp2 : " << temp2 << " --  Temp3 : " << temp3 << endl;
            temp3 = temp2->next;
            temp2->next = temp1;
            temp1->next = temp3;
            cout << "IN IF AFTER NODES SWAP" << endl;

        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

**Sample test with output ran through Valgrind shows a lot of errors**

```
==14392== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14392== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14392== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14392== Command: ./singleLinkedList
==14392== 
No nodes added yet!
Enter number of nodes that you want to add: 5

9

9 has been appended to the list 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2

2 has been appended to the list 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
4

4 has been appended to the list 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
6

6 has been appended to the list 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
8

8 has been appended to the list 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
9 2 4 6 8 
IN FOR

IN FOR

IN FOR
IN IF BEFORE NODES SWAP
==14392== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14392==    at 0x4F36E01: int std::__int_to_char<char, unsigned long>(char*, unsigned long, char const*, std::_Ios_Fmtflags, bool) (locale_facets.tcc:826)
==14392==    by 0x4F3845B: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<unsigned long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, unsigned long) const (locale_facets.tcc:876)
==14392==    by 0x4F3864E: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, void const*) const (locale_facets.tcc:1191)
==14392==    by 0x4F45729: put (locale_facets.h:2460)
==14392==    by 0x4F45729: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*) (ostream.tcc:73)
==14392==    by 0x4010AE: linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int, int) (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392==    by 0x400AEA: main (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14392==    at 0x400F86: linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int, int) (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392== 
==14392== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14392==    at 0x4F36E08: int std::__int_to_char<char, unsigned long>(char*, unsigned long, char const*, std::_Ios_Fmtflags, bool) (locale_facets.tcc:824)
==14392==    by 0x4F3845B: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<unsigned long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, unsigned long) const (locale_facets.tcc:876)
==14392==    by 0x4F3864E: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, void const*) const (locale_facets.tcc:1191)
==14392==    by 0x4F45729: put (locale_facets.h:2460)
==14392==    by 0x4F45729: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*) (ostream.tcc:73)
==14392==    by 0x4010AE: linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int, int) (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392==    by 0x400AEA: main (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14392==    at 0x400F86: linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int, int) (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392== 
==14392== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14392==    at 0x4F38564: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<unsigned long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, unsigned long) const (locale_facets.tcc:905)
==14392==    by 0x4F3864E: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, void const*) const (locale_facets.tcc:1191)
==14392==    by 0x4F45729: put (locale_facets.h:2460)
==14392==    by 0x4F45729: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*) (ostream.tcc:73)
==14392==    by 0x4010AE: linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int, int) (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392==    by 0x400AEA: main (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14392==    at 0x400F86: linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int, int) (in /home/captainmoha/uni/data_structure/singleLinkedList)
==14392== 
Temp1 : 0x5aa7d20 --  Temp2 : 0x5aa7d70 --  Temp3 : 0xffefffca0
IN IF AFTER NODES SWAP
9 2 4 8 ==14392== 
==14392== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14392==     in use at exit: 72,784 bytes in 6 blocks
==14392==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 0 frees, 72,784 bytes allocated
==14392== 
==14392== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14392==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==14392==    indirectly lost: 48 bytes in 3 blocks
==14392==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14392==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==14392==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14392== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==14392== 
==14392== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14392== ERROR SUMMARY: 19 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: At which line do you get the segmentation fault? Try adding more cout statements if you need to narrow it down, or use a debugger to find out on which line it crashes.

Comment: @KLibby I added a sample test with the output. I think it goes in through the if one time and then it happens. I think that means that there is something wrong with the way that I am swapping them.

Comment: I don't think the swap is causing a segfault, although you do have a memory leak. If you aren't flushing `cout` (either use `flush` or `cout << endl`), it might be segfaulting before more text is sent to the screen.

Comment: From the output, you can see that the `swapTwoAdjacent` function does complete, but the root of the problem probably starts in that function, as the crash happens later, either in the display or count functions when you try to traverse the list. Either use a debugger, and check that the values of all the variables are correct as you step through, or work out a very small example on paper, (start with, e.g. a 2-element list) following the steps of your code. You can also add some more debugging lines to print the variables in your swap function, to check that they are as they should be.

Comment: @KLibby Just tried it without the count function and it is still segfaulting.

Comment: @JamesRoot Could you please tell me where the memory leak is ?

Comment: @KLibby I ran it through Valgrind and the segfault appears to happening inside the swapTwoAdjacent function. Edited the post with the Valgrind output.

Comment: @MohamedAli Your entire class. I didn't see a single `delete`. Use a debugger and find where the pointers go wrong!

Comment: @JamesRoot You are right. I forgot I haven't implemented the destructor yet. Sorry :)

Comment: `...temp1 = temp1->next, temp2 = temp1->next)` I just noticed this seems strange. Should temp2 in fact be set to temp**2**->next here? The way it is written in your code, every time you enter the `for()` (after the first time), temp1 and temp2 are both set to the same node.

Comment: @KLibby You are right! I just correct it. The segfault is gone. Thank you!

Comment: @KLibby The output is still wrong though. If I enter 5 elements 9 2 4 6 8
I get this output 9 2 4 8. So now I think it has lost the 6 node.

Comment: @Klibby In a weird twist of fate, that doesn't fix the bug, but instead introduces another bug that seems to prevent the original bug.

Comment: In that case, @MohamedAli, I'd go with a small example on paper , work it through step by step according to your code (it's not that long) and you'll pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @KLibby I have been at it for over five hours now tried papers pieces of legos and still :D . Not gonna sleep before it's working. Hopefully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to swap two nodes, you end up removing one instead.

```
if (temp1->data == num1 && temp2->data == num2)
{
    temp3 = temp2->next; //temp# == node# at this moment
    temp2->next = temp1; //node2 now links back to node1
    temp1->next = temp3; //node1 now skips node2 and goes to node3
}
```

After this code executes, you now have removed the node I call `node2` from the list. And because of how you're for loop is written, you end up at the end of your list sooner than expected, and try to dereference a null pointer. In your for loop:

```
temp1 = temp1->next, /*temp1->next now points to last node*/
temp2 = temp1->next /*temp2 is now a null pointer*/
```

So the loop condition `temp2->next != NULL` fails because `temp2` is NULL itself.

In the comments, it was discovered that changing `temp2 = temp1->next` to `temp2 = temp2->next` makes the segfault stop. This is because `temp2->next` pointed back to `node`, and so it took more iterations to reach the end, where the loop failed. If you just `return` from the function after the "swap", you won't have this error.

EDIT: I've added the code to swap two nodes.

```
void linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int num1, int num2)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    node** np = &head; //two star programmer club
    node* temp;
    while ((*np)->next != NULL) //As long as next node exists
    {
        if ((*np)->data == num1 && (*np)->next->data == num2)
        {
            temp = *np; //temp = &node1
            *np = (*np)->next; //node0->next = &node2
            temp->next = (*np)->next; //node1->next = node2->next
            (*np)->next = temp; //node2->next = node1
            //node0->node2->node1->node3
            //If you want to only swap the first pair of values you find, uncomment the next line, otherwise it swaps every matching pair
            //return;
        }
        np = &((*np)->next); //Point to pointer to next node
    }
}
```

By using a pointer to pointer to node, we can modify the pointer that was pointing to the current node we are iterating over. The comments hopefully explain what the assignments all are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now understand what was causing the segfault. I still can't get my head around the swapping steps. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: I was going to originally, but my pizza arrived first. I'll update the answer with how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it. Bon Appetit!

Comment: Thank you! Looks great and I really appreciate the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

For the record I got it to work using three pointers. My problem was that I didn't have a way to know the node before the two nodes I'm swapping so I kept losing a node.

**This is the working method with comments that hopefully explain what I did:**

```
void linkedList::swapTwoAdjacent(int num1, int num2) {
    node *temp1, *temp2, *temp3;


    temp1 = head;
    temp2 = temp1->next;

    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (head->next == NULL) {
        cout << "Swap not possible! List has only one node." << endl;
    }

    else if (temp1->data == num1 && temp2->data == num2) {      // if the nodes to swap are the first two nodes
                head->next = temp2->next;   // make the next of head point to the third node
                temp2->next = head;         // make the next of the second node point to head
                head = temp2;               // now make the second node the head
            }


    else {
        node *tempHolder1, *tempHolder2, *tempHolder3;  // holders for nodes in temps to make swapping easier

        // go through nodes in the list with three pointers
        // temp1->temp2->temp3
        // I'm using three pointers so that I always know the node before the two nodes I'm looking for

        for (temp1 = head, temp2 = temp1->next, temp3 = temp2->next; temp3 != NULL; temp1 = temp1->next, temp2 = temp1->next, temp3 = temp2->next) {
            // cout << "IN FOR" << endl;

            if (temp2->data == num1 && temp3->data == num2) { // if the two nodes are found

                // these are just placeholders to make swapping easier

                tempHolder1 = temp1;    // now temp1 is the node before the two nodes I want to swap
                tempHolder2 = temp2;    // temp2 is the first node
                tempHolder3 = temp3;    // temp3 is the second node

                temp1->next = tempHolder2->next;        // make the first node point to the third node
                temp2->next = tempHolder3->next;        // make the second node point to what's after the third node
                temp3->next = tempHolder2;              // make the third node point to the second node

                break;

            }

            else {
                continue;
            }
        }

    }

}
```